# Unable to prompt the message to required field in reactive forms

Tags: html, node.js, angular, typescript, angular-reactive-forms

When I am trying to prompt the message to the username field I am getting the error of `(Object is possibly 'null')`

My template html file:

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
      <form [formGroup]="login" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">
        <div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="">Username</label>
            <input class="form-control" formControlName="name" type="text" />
            <div
              *ngIf="getControl.touched && getControl.invalid"
              class="text-danger"
            >
              <div *ngIf="getControl.errors?.required">Name is required.</div>
              <div *ngIf="getControl.errors?.minlength">
                Minimum 4 character are required.
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="">Email</label>
            <input class="form-control" type="text" formControlName="Email" />
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <div *ngFor="let gender of genders">
            <label>
              <input
                type="radio"
                name="gender"
                [value]="gender"
                formControlName="gender"
              />{{gender}}
            </label>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="mt-2">
          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

This is my `ReactiveformsComponent.ts` file

```js
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import {
  FormBuilder,
  FormControl,
  FormGroup,
  RequiredValidator,
  Validators,
} from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-reactiveforms',
  templateUrl: './reactiveforms.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./reactiveforms.component.css'],
})
export class ReactiveformsComponent implements OnInit {

  genders = ['Male', 'Female'];
  login: FormGroup;
  constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.login = this.fb.group({
      name: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(4)]],
      Email: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.email]],
      gender: ['', [Validators.required]]
    });
  }

  onSubmit() {
    console.log(this.login.value);
  }

  get getControl() {
    return this.login.get("name");
  }
}
```

If I declared `login` with `!` operator like this, that is when it works.

```js
login!: FormGroup;
```

These are the error messages I am getting:

> ```
> Unable to declaring my form instance variable (login) -- error TS2531: Object is possibly 'null'.
> ```

If I make it like `(login!: FormGroup;)`, it is working fine.

Comment: use safe operator also in getControl `*ngIf="getControl?.touched && getControl?.invalid"` or  `*ngIf="getControl && getControl.touched && getControl.invalid"` .Also you getter can be like `get getControl(){return this.login?this.login.get('name'):null}`

Comment: @Eliseo thank you for solution it's working on for main prompt but the child div are not working it shows the  Error: src/app/reactiveforms/reactiveforms.component.html:11:55 - error TS2531: Object is possibly 'null'.
11                         <div *ngIf="getControl.errors?.minlength">Minimum 4 character are required.</div>
                                                         ~~~~~~~~~

Comment: also in `*ngIf="getControl?.errors?.minlength·`

Answer (score 0):

Do you have the FormsModule and the ReactiveFormsModule imported in your app.module.ts? I copied your code and imported those and it worked.

I threw a debugger in the onSubmit after your console log and it receives the values added.

Comment: Yes, I have imported reactive forms in module.ts even getting error

Answer (score 0):

The reason when you use the `!` **null assertion operator** works is because you are telling typescript that `login: FormGroup` is not going to be `null` and it will be initialize later.

Your code is fine, because, on your `ngOnInit`, you are indeed, making sure `this.login` is created.

```js
 ngOnInit(): void {
       this.login = this.fb.group({        
       name: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(4)]],
       Email: ['',[Validators.required,Validators.email]],         
       gender: ['', [Validators.required]]
    });
```

You can read about it [here](https://www.logicbig.com/tutorials/misc/typescript/non-null-assertion-operator.html)